# Is passing a function just a link? Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

When using Javascript as follows:

```
function Test(Example) {
}

Test.prototype.etc etc etc


function Example() {
}


Example.prototype.etc etc etc


example = new Example();
test = new Test(example);
```

Is this efficient or am I hogging memory somehow?

I ask this as I have the following setup within my javascript game at present and each requires some of the other (in brackets):

Camera (canvas)
Input (canvas, camera, tilemap)
Sprite (camera, canvas)

Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I be passing this method some other way? It's struck me as a concern as I now have quite a few new instances of sprite and wondered if it is going to become a problem.

Cheers

Comment: javascript isn't a strict language, therefore when you do `function Test(Example) {` you're not getting the Example of `function Example() {`, you're just naming a argument. You realize this right?

Comment: To re-explain, I have a camera which calculates various things about what the user should be seeing. This is passed into a number of different 'classes' (for want of a better word in Javascripts case?) - each of the classes it is passed to then assigns it as this.camera = camera. Then the functions within that class can all access what the camera is doing. It's working correctly. I'm just wondering if it is inefficient or there is a better way.

Comment: Oh if you meant do I realise that when I pass example into Test I don't get a new example I get the same one, then yes I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript objects (and functions) are not copied when they are passed as parameters. Take a look at the following code (or test it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdleyEskridge/5MRYh/)):

```
function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype.property = 5;
function incrementProperty(parameter) { parameter.property++; };

var foo = new Foo();

alert(foo.property); // 5
incrementProperty(foo);
alert(foo.property); // 6
alert(new Foo().property); // 5, because it's a new object
```

The `foo` object is *not* copied when it is passed to the `bar` function. This is demonstrated by the fact that `foo`'s `property` retains is value back outside of the method. Put simply, `foo` and `parameter` point to the same object.

Keep in mind that they *themselves* aren't the same object, though. If you reassign `parameter` to point to new value within the `bar` function (`parameter = "dummy";`), `foo` will be not be affected. Does that distinction make sense?

Note: JavaScript strings and numbers *are* copied when they are passed as parameters, though.

Comment: I assumed that was the case as the above was happening for me. Just wanted to make sure. :)